# How would I go around making a picker for units?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I'm new at Swift and I'm looking to make a unit converter app to test my skills. Here's my attempt at making a picker:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var inputNumber = ""
@State private var inputUnit = 2
@State private var outputUnit = ""

let inputUnits = ["meters", "kilometers", "feet", "yard", "miles"]
let outputUnits = ["meters", "kilometers", "feet", "yard", "miles"]
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("Enter measurement", text: $inputNumber)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)

                Picker("Your unit", selection: $inputUnit) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< inputUnits.count) {
                        Text("\(self.inputUnits)")
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the parameter to the closure, which is an index

```
Picker(selection: $inputUnit, label: Text("Your unit")) {
    ForEach(0 ..< inputUnits.count) {
        Text("\(self.inputUnits[$0])") //<- $0 is the index for your array
    }
}
```